# Yii generate errors from parent controller

Tags: yii, error-handling

I just started using Yii, coming from Codeigniter (CI). I'm trying to set up a situation where the application will check a users credentials before they can even access the site. In CI, I would create a parent controller, put my checks in there, and then inherit that parent controller. I've been trying to do the same thing with Yii, but with no luck.

I first created an init() method (for some reason I can't put the code in a __construct() method). I then perform my check, which works fine. I can throw a new CHttpException, but that looks ugly. How do I use Yii's built in error handling to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: What kind of response do you want to show based on the result of the check?

Comment: I want to show an error saying that they cannot use this site

Comment: Well, what's the problem in rendering an error view?

Comment: I tried just rendering a view from the parent controller, which it did, but it also rendered the view from the child controller.  So I ended up with "two" websites being viewed, the top one saying that access is denied, and the bottom one with a welcome screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by sending the error to the site/error view and then calling Yii::app()->end() to keep the child controllers from loading.

Answer (score 0):

For simple login rules you should just implement the 'accessControl' filters from Yii see [Yii documentation on authorizations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth).

Another way would be to throw the Exception like you already did, and write custom Http error views, place it in the yerfolder/protected/views/system/ (see the yii/framework/views directory for examples)

Comment: I tried your second suggestion, and I couldn't get it to work.  It would never load the view.  I'm reading into your first suggestion right now and trying to figure out if it will work for my situation.  It seems that the documentation talks about authorization on an individual (child) controller level, not on a sitewide (parent) level.  I'm using this on an intranet at my company and I have to verify users based on pki, and Yii's built in authorization is based on username, password.

Comment: I solved this by sending the error to the site/error view and then calling Yii::app()->end() to keep the child controllers from loading.

Comment: ahh... cmiiw you want to check the authorization BEFORE even the controller action was called? kinda like the beforeFilter in cakephp? if this is the case, check out http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller specifically chapter 4, filters :D

Comment: Yii also has a "beforeAction"-function in the controller that is called before the actual action will be executed. It's very easy to override this function. If the access is denied you just throw a new CHttpException(404, 'Access Denied') and everything is aborted and the error view is rendered.